# In android toolbar when icon is made rotating using animation it is shifting its position towards left

Tags: android, animation, rotation

When i am trying to rotate an icon in toolbar using animation, it starts rotating but it is shifting towards left.

Below is the code I used for making the icon start rotating and stop rotating

```
private MenuItem refreshItem;
    private Animation animRotate;
    private ImageButton imgRotate;
```

refreshItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_btn_refresh);

```
public void refresh() {
            flag = 1;
        if (imgRotate == null) {
            /* Attach a rotating ImageView to the refresh item as an ActionView */
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            imgRotate = (ImageButton ) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.view_action_refresh, null);
            // define the animation for rotation
            animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mActivity, anim.rotate);
            animRotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        }
        imgRotate.startAnimation(animRotate);
        refreshItem.setActionView(imgRotate);
    }

    public void completeRefresh() {
        flag = 0;
        if (refreshItem != null) {
            refreshItem.getActionView().clearAnimation();
            refreshItem.setActionView(null);
        }
    }
```

can anyone please suggest if i need to change anything to stop shifting of icon in toolbar when it is rotating.

Comment: could you show animation code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably caused by incorrect layout for your `imgRotate`, see if this helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/menu_animation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="@*android:dimen/action_button_min_width"
    android:padding="8dp"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    tools:ignore="PrivateResource" />
```

Comment: thank you very much, its working for me when i change style as mentioned above.